# New to tensorflow, gradient descent weight doesn't change

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

this is my first question.
It probably is a stupid question, but I cannot solve it. As I run my code below, W and b stays the same(no matter I set them as 1 or 0). My train_x are numerous RGB value, and train_y are the corresponding classes(0 or 1).
No matter how many steps taken, it never moves. Also, accuracy is always 1.

```
train_x = np.loadtxt('matrix1',dtype= int)#[[r,g,b],[r,g,b],...]
train_y = np.loadtxt('matrix2',dtype= int)#[0,0,0,0,0,...,1,1,1,1,1]
#machine learning

sess = tf.Session()

x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 3])
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3,2]))#first: 3 factors(rgb) ; second: 2 categories(red, white)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

for num in range(100):
    number_selected = random.sample(range(0,len(train_x)-1) , 1000)#number_selected: random selection of data for training
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: [train_x[num] for num in number_selected], y_: [[train_y[num]] for num in number_selected]})
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
number_selected = random.sample(range(0,len(train_x)-1) , 10)#number_selected: random numbers for training
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: [train_x[num] for num in number_selected], y_: [[train_y[num]] for num in number_selected]}))
print(sess.run(W),sess.run(b))
```

Comment: Don't initialize your weights to zero.

Comment: Thanks. But after I set W and b to 1 or 0.5, the results are still the same(the weight stays the same).

Comment: You should use different random weights for each dimension. It's bad to have symmetry in the initial weights. Also consider using the softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits loss function

Comment: I just cannot solve the problem. I think there is a bug because my train_step,cross_entropy are none,0

Comment: Yeah your cross entropy formula is wrong and that is making your gradients be zero. You should use the sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits or softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits function.

Comment: However, I still failed after using this two functions. I've also tried them on a simple program which originally calculated loss using square function. But instead of converge, weight and bias both diverge. I am really confused. By the way, I tried different step sizes from 0.01 to 1.